# Is it possible to have separate git ignore rules for each remote?

Tags: git, .htaccess, .htpasswd

Here's my situation.  I'm setting up a development server and a production server on PHP Fog.  I have one set of files on my local machine that I'd like to be able to work on and push to each of the 2 servers on PHP Fog.

I want my development server to be protected though, using traditional htpasswd/htaccess methods.  This means the production server needs to ignore those two files in my working copy.

Is there a way to tell the production server to ignore those two files when a commit is made but let them go through when pushing to the development server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking in to this a while back as well and I used this article, it should explain how to use a single htaccess for multiple sites rather than worrying about git.

Blog post: "[Single `.htaccess` file in your git repo for both your dev and production server](http://www.markalanevans.com/2010/07/30/single-htaccess-file-for-both-your-dev-and-production-code/)" by [Mark Alan Evans](http://www.markalanevans.com/resume/)

He described the problem thusly:

> #### Problem:
>
> You want to have `dev.yoursite.com` and `www.yoursite.com` but you don’t want `dev.yoursite.com` visible to the public.
>
> #### Solution:
>
> If your using apache(which many of us are), `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` to the rescue.
>   In your `.htaccess` file add:

```
SetEnvIf Host yourstagingserver.com passreq 
AuthType Basic 
AuthName “Staging Server” 
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd 
Require valid-user 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
Deny from env=passreq 
Satisfy any
```

> #### Configure your password file on both dev & production
>
> Wherever you specify the `/path/to/.htpasswd` file, navigate to that folder from the console and type “`htpasswd -c .htpasswd mark`”  where mark is the first user you want to create a login for.
>   For each additonal person type “`htpasswd .htpasswd linda`”  where `linda` is the next username you want to add to the `.htpasswd` file.
>   Each time  it will prompt you to type in the password twice (your password will be stored in the `.htpasswd` file) encrypted next to the username you created.
>
> Note:

`AuthUserFile` expects an absolute path, but if you don't start your path with a forward slash, it defaults to the directory you specify in your `httpd.conf` file as `ServerRoot`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I ended up using RewriteCond methods in place of SetEnvIf but it's the same principle.

Comment: I took the liberty to add the blog post content. If it someday disappear, you will still find the solution on Stack Overflow (for all eternity, with [Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/ ).